# Using SendGrid with PHP and jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Ok so I'm stuck here. I've been trying to put up a web form so that I can be notified of users who sign up for my mobile app via **e-mail**. I want to override **ajax's** default behavior because **EVENTUALLY**(as in not at the moment) I want the submission not to be handled for the first few pages.

My goal is to have the user submit the **jQuery Mobile** form, have **ajax** send the form data to my **php script** which will **e-mail** the user data to me using the **SendGrid** api. But right now it's not working for me.

The page is hosted on a google compute engine instance running Linux, PHP is correctly installed, the form appears and even refreshes when the **SEND** button is clicked but no e-mail ='(

BTW **SendGrid** works fine from my server when launched from the command line using **Postfix**

The link to the tutorial is here: [Sending E-mails with SendGrid using Compute Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid)

Help please?

**mailer.php** followed by  **postScript.js** followed by **web-form-complete.php**

```
     <?php    
            $action = $_POST['subscribePage']; 
            $formData = json_decode($_POST['formData']); 
            $fname = $formData->{'fname'}; 
            $lname = $formData->{'lname'}; 
            $busname = $formData->{'busname'}; 
            $bustype = $formData->{'bustype'}; 
            $selectmenu = $formData->{'selectmenu'};

            $sendgrid = new SendGrid("[-----API-KEY-----]");
            $email    = new SendGrid\Email();

            { $body = "{$fname} {$lname} \n{$busname} \n{$bustype}  \n{$selectmenu}"; }


            $email->addTo("admin@my-privatedomain.com") 
                ->setFrom("admin@my-privatedomain.com") // for testing purposes
                ->setSubject("Verification Request")
                ->setHtml($body);

            $sendgrid->send($email);
        ?>
```

```js
$(document).on('pageinit', '#subscribePage', function(){
            $(document).on('click', '#submit', function() { // catch the form's submit event
                if($('#fname').val().length > 0 && $('#lname').val().length   && $('#busname').val().length > 0){
                    
                        $.ajax({url: 'mailer.php',
                            data: {action : 'subscribePage', formData : $('#subscribeContent').serialize()},
                            type: 'post',
                            async: 'true',
                            dataType: 'JSON',
                            beforeSend: function() {
                            },
                            complete: function() {
                            },
                            success: function (result) {
                                } else {
                                    alert('Submission Unsuccessful!');
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (request,error) {
                                alert('Network error has occurred');
                            }
                        });
                } else {
                    alert('Please fill all necessary fields');
                }
                return false;
            });
    });
```

```html
    

<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Verification</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    
    <!--For JQuery mobile UI widgets -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    <div data-role="page" id="subscribePage">
    
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Verification</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    
    <!-- Start Here: Web Form tutorial -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="subscribeBox">
    
    <h2><span class="thin">Create A Verified</span> XXXX <span class="thin">Account</span></h2>
        <p>Please fill out the following information to receive our verification. Verification should take less than 24 hours.</p>
    
    <form id="subscribeContent" class="subscribeForm" data-ajax="false" >
    <!-- name fields here -->
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <input id="fname" type="text" placeholder="First Name*" Name="First Name" required><br>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
     <input id="lname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name*" name="Last Name" required><br>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
     <input id="busname" type="text" placeholder="Business/Organization Name*" name="Business/Organization Name" required><br>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">

    <!-- Other form fields here.... -->

    <!-- radio buttons here -->
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <legend>Option</legend>
        <input type="radio" class="bustype" name="bustype" id="radio1" value="Local Business/Organization" />
        <label for="local">Local Business/Organization</label>
        <input type="radio" class="bustype" name="bustype" id="radio2" value="Worldwide Brand" />
        <label for="worldwide">Worldwide Brand</label>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
        
    <!-- dynamic fields here -->
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="selectmenu" class="select">Options:</label>
      <select name="selectmenu" id="selectmenu">
    
     
     <option value="bank">Bank</option>
     <option value="car_dealer">Car Dealer</option>
     <option value="car_rental">Car Rental</option>
     <option value="car_repair">Car Repair</option>
     
        <!-- Other SelectMenu options here -->
        </select>
    </div>
    <!-- submit button here -->
     <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
           
    </form>
      
    
    <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>XXXX App</h4>
    </div> <!-- /main --> 
    </div> <!-- /header --> 
    </div> <!-- /page -->
    <script src="postScript.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are issues in your all scripts. Try this:

**web-form-complete.php**

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Verification</title>    
     <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!--For JQuery mobile UI widgets -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div data-role="page" id="subscribePage">

    <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Verification</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <!-- Start Here: Web Form tutorial -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="subscribeBox">

    <h2><span class="thin">Create A Verified</span> XXXX <span class="thin">Account</span></h2>
        <p>Please fill out the following information to receive our verification. Verification should take less than 24 hours.</p>

    <form id="subscribeContent" class="subscribeForm" data-ajax="false" >
    <!-- name fields here -->
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <input id="fname" type="text" placeholder="First Name*" Name="fname" required><br>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <input id="lname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name*" name="lname" required><br>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <input id="busname" name="busname" placeholder="Business/Organization Name*" required><br>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">

    <!-- Other form fields here.... -->

    <!-- radio buttons here -->
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <legend>Option</legend>
        <input type="radio" class="bustype" name="bustype" id="radio1" value="Local Business/Organization" />
        <label for="local">Local Business/Organization</label>
        <input type="radio" class="bustype" name="bustype" id="radio2" value="Worldwide Brand" />
        <label for="worldwide">Worldwide Brand</label>
      </fieldset>
    </div>

    <!-- dynamic fields here -->
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="selectmenu" class="select">Options:</label>
      <select name="selectmenu" id="selectmenu">


        <option value="bank">Bank</option>
        <option value="car_dealer">Car Dealer</option>
        <option value="car_rental">Car Rental</option>
        <option value="car_repair">Car Repair</option>

        <!-- Other SelectMenu options here -->
        </select>
    </div>
    <!-- submit button here -->
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send">

    </form>


    <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>XXXX App</h4>
    </div> <!-- /main --> 
    </div> <!-- /header --> 
    </div> <!-- /page -->
    <script src="postScript.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**postScript.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
            $(document).on('click', '#submit', function(e) { // catch the form's submit event
                if($('#fname').val().length > 0 && $('#lname').val().length   && $('#busname').val().length > 0){
                        console.log("in...");
                        var data = $('#subscribeContent').serialize();
                        $.ajax({url: 'mailer.php',
                            data: data,
                            type: 'post',
                            async: 'true',
                            dataType: 'JSON',
                            beforeSend: function() {
                            },
                            complete: function() {
                            },
                            success: function (result) {
                                //write your proper condtion 
                                console.log(result);
                            },
                            error: function (request,error) {
                                alert('Network error has occurred');
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                        });
                } else {
                    alert('Please fill all necessary fields');
                }
                return false;
            });
    });
```

**mailer.php**

```
 <?php    
            //$action = $_POST['action'];             
            $fname = $_POST['fname']; 
            $lname = $_POST['lname']; 
            $busname = $_POST['busname']; 
            $bustype = $_POST['bustype']; 
            $selectmenu = $_POST['selectmenu'];

            $sendgrid = new SendGrid("[-----API-KEY-----]");
            $email    = new SendGrid\Email();

            { $body = "{$fname} {$lname} \n{$busname} \n{$bustype}  \n{$selectmenu}"; }


            $email->addTo("admin@my-privatedomain.com") 
                ->setFrom("admin@my-privatedomain.com") // for testing purposes
                ->setSubject("Verification Request")
                ->setHtml($body);

            $sendgrid->send($email);
        ?>
```

**Also make sure you have included SendGrid library in your file and also you have set valid API-KEY.**